# Mapping table with data files based on data type of the data file using python?

Tags: python, scala, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have 4 text files 2 file contain database tables details and other 2 contain data,like below.

```
table1.txt
ename:varchar(10)
eid:smallint(5)
esal:numeric(10,3)

table2.txt
sid:smallint(5)
sname:varchar(10)
sclass:varchar(10)
```

and my data files  are like below  the file names also not fixed nemas i.e it will change

```
file1.txt:
aa,1,12222.009
bb,2,12345.012

file2.txt
1,s1,1st_class
2,s2,2nd_class
```

so now I want to map which table which file match  will match based on data type of the data. my expected output should be like below.

my expected output will be in other log file or print statement :

```
table1 matched data file is file2.txt.
table2 matched  data file is file1.txt.
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: i have tried using pyspark by creating dataframes but it is not happening

Comment: I actually.. i need both ways. but python is main

Comment: if it is Scala answer..i can convert into python...i am trying both ways which i know (scala and python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the case is not clear so it might be differently. However I can give some suggestions. It is not the exact solution but I think it may help you to give an idea.

First I read tables details;

```
>>> rdd1 = sc.textFile('/home/ali/table1.txt')
>>> table1 = rdd1.map(lambda x: x.split(':')).map(lambda x: (x[0],x[1])).toDF(['col_name','data_type'])
>>> table1.show()
+--------+-------------+
|col_name|    data_type|
+--------+-------------+
|   ename|  varchar(10)|
|     eid|  smallint(5)|
|    esal|numeric(10,3)|
+--------+-------------+

>>> rdd2 = sc.textFile('/home/ali/table2.txt')
>>> table2 = rdd2.map(lambda x: x.split(':')).map(lambda x: (x[0],x[1])).toDF(['col_name','data_type'])
>>> table2.show()
+--------+-----------+
|col_name|  data_type|
+--------+-----------+
|     sid|smallint(5)|
|   sname|varchar(10)|
|  sclass|varchar(10)|
+--------+-----------+
```

And I read data files but before this you should define schemas. If you don't, all columns' data type will be assigned as string as a default

```
>>> from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, DoubleType, IntegerType, StringType
>>> 
>>> schema1 = StructType([
...     StructField("col1", StringType()),
...     StructField("col2", IntegerType()),
...     StructField("col3", DoubleType())
... ])
>>> 
>>> schema2 = StructType([
...     StructField("col1", IntegerType()),
...     StructField("col2", StringType()),
...     StructField("col3", StringType())
... ])
>>> 
>>> data1 = spark.read.csv('/home/ali/file1.txt', schema=schema1)
>>> data1.show()
+----+----+---------+
|col1|col2|     col3|
+----+----+---------+
|  aa|   1|12222.009|
|  bb|   2|12345.012|
+----+----+---------+

>>> data2 = spark.read.csv('/home/ali/file2.txt', schema=schema2)
>>> data2.show()
+----+----+---------+
|col1|col2|     col3|
+----+----+---------+
|   1|  s1|1st_class|
|   2|  s2|2nd_class|
+----+----+---------+
```

I define a function to check if data types are matched or not. But when you define a function you should convert some database data types(ex: varchar -> string, numeric -> double ..) I convert only for string, int and double data types. If you will work more data types you should define all of them

```
>>> def matchTableData(t,d):
...     matched = []
...     for k1,table in t.items():
...             table_dtypes = []
...             a = True
...             for i in [i.data_type for i in table.select('data_type').collect()]:
...                     if 'char' in i:
...                             table_dtypes.append('string')
...                     elif 'int' in i:
...                             table_dtypes.append('int')
...                     elif 'numeric' in i:
...                             table_dtypes.append('double')
...             for k2,data in d.items():
...                     data_dtypes = [i[1] for i in data.dtypes]
...                     if table_dtypes == data_dtypes:
...                             matched.append([k1,k2])
...     return matched
```

Now we are ready to compare data types. I create two dicts for tables and data.

```
>>> tables = {'table1':table1, 'table2':table2}
>>> data = {'data1':data1, 'data2':data2}
>>> print(matchTableData(tables,data))
[['table1', 'data1'], ['table2', 'data2']]
```

As you can see it returns matched ones. As I said before it might not be exact solution but I think you can use some part of this

Comment: Hi Thanks for Quick reply, but i can't  create schema1  hard coded values schema1 should generate dynamically.in above answer (schema1,schema2) should be dynamically

Comment: you can use Pandas for this. import pandas as pd   data1 = spark.createDataFrame(pd.read_csv('/home/cloudera/ali/file1.txt'))

Comment: can i use options(header='false', inferschema='true') ,instead of pandas?